# how do I pass the User under [Service] to the OnFailure unit in systemd

Tags: rhel, systemd

I have a systemd unit which runs as a specific user (not root).
This unit has an OnFailure with 1 other systemd unit.
In this OnFailure unit the ExecStart starts a shell script which sends a email.
I want to pass to this shell script the user from the originating system unit which failed.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to start a unit whilst passing a parameter is to use instances and start `unit@parameter` then recover this value inside the unit with `%I`.
For example, using `--user` for testing, file `~/.config/systemd/user/tryfail.service`:

```
[Unit]
User=otheruser
OnFailure=fail@otheruser.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 3;exit 7'
```

and `~/.config/systemd/user/fail@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=%I Instance of Fail Service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo got %i'
StandardOutput=journal
```

Now the commands

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start tryfail
journalctl -f
```

should show you the fail service being started with `otheruser` as info. Obviously, the `User=` is ignored when testing with `--user`, but this is of no consequence.